# How to apply an axiom to simplify a match in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have this code

```
Parameter foo : nat -> option bool.

Definition foo_valid x :=
  match foo x with
      Some _ => True
    | None => False
  end.

Axiom foo_is_valid : forall x, foo x = Some true.

Lemma foo_some_is_true_for_real : forall {x : nat}, foo_valid x.
  cbv.
  intros.
```

At this point I have this goal

```
x : nat

========================= (1 / 1)

match foo x with
| Some _ => True
| None => False
end
```

Is it possible to use `foo_is_valid` axiom to eliminate the match and finish the proof? How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo_is_valid x` is an equality so you can use it to rewrite.
The easiest way to do so is using the [`rewrite` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.rewrite).

```
rewrite foo_is_valid.
```

should replace `foo x` by `Some true` in your goal, and then `simpl` will make the `match` compute.

Comment: Thank you so much Théo!

I tough that ending with `True` would complete the goal, but it doesn't I end up with `True` in the goal, I can finish it with _easy_ but I'm missing some point here. I tough that the goal were to take all goes to True, but it seems that this is wrong, what I'm missing?

Comment: No, `True` is a type with one constructor that is `I`. You can conclude with `exact I.` or with `constructor.` typically.